# RUN command not executed in dockerfile image building

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have following file structure

```
Django/
  - IoT.yml
  - Dockerfile_Build_Django
  - requirements.txt
```

My dockerfile (Dockerfile_Build_Django) for budiding image is as below:

```
FROM python:3.10.0a7-alpine3.13
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

My docker-compose file as below:

```
  Django_2.2:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_Build_Django
    # Give an image name/tag
    image: python:3.10.0a7-alpine3.13 
    container_name: Django_2.2
    depends_on: 
      - Django_Mongo_4.2.12
    tty: true
```

after "docker-compose -f IoT.yml up" to setup and run container, then I use "docker exec -it Django_2.2 /bin/sh" to SSH access the Django_2.2 container, I found:

1. no folder "/code" was created according to "RUN mkdir /code/" in docker file
2. nothing was copied over to working directory according to dockerfile.
3. Django was not installed according to above dockerfile.

```
[root@Mysite Django]# docker image ls
REPOSITORY    TAG                   IMAGE ID       CREATED       SIZE
python        3.10.0a7-alpine3.13   bba91cdea5a1   3 days ago    44.9MB
django_2.2    iot                   37c35b93c3d8   6 days ago    86.3MB

[root@MySite Django]# docker history python:3.10.0a7-alpine3.13 
IMAGE          CREATED       CREATED BY                                      SIZE      COMMENT
bba91cdea5a1   3 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["python3"]              0B        
<missing>      3 days ago    /bin/sh -c set -ex;   wget -O get-pip.py "$P…   8.01MB    
<missing>      3 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_SHA256…   0B        
<missing>      3 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_GET_PIP_URL=ht…   0B        
<missing>      3 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_PIP_VERSION=21…   0B        
<missing>      3 days ago    /bin/sh -c cd /usr/local/bin  && ln -s idle3…   32B       
<missing>      3 days ago    /bin/sh -c set -ex  && apk add --no-cache --…   29.5MB    
<missing>      3 days ago    /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PYTHON_VERSION=3.10.0…   0B        
<missing>      10 days ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV GPG_KEY=A035C8C19219B…   0B        
<missing>      10 days ago   /bin/sh -c set -eux;  apk add --no-cache   c…   1.76MB    
<missing>      10 days ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV LANG=C.UTF-8             0B        
<missing>      11 days ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV PATH=/usr/local/bin:/…   0B        
<missing>      11 days ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["/bin/sh"]              0B        
<missing>      11 days ago   /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:7119167b56ff1228b…   5.61MB    

[root@MySite Django]# docker-compose -f IoT.yml build 
Django_Mongo_4.2.12 uses an image, skipping
Building Django_2.2
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.832MB

Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.10.0a7-alpine3.13
 ---> bba91cdea5a1
Step 2/7 : ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 0
 ---> Running in 4f04eff80f44
Removing intermediate container 4f04eff80f44
 ---> 894fa6105e9b
Step 3/7 : RUN mkdir /code/
 ---> Running in 41a547193037
Removing intermediate container 41a547193037
 ---> 08d8a6605228
Step 4/7 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in 1d33ed47543f
Removing intermediate container 1d33ed47543f
 ---> f4f22bc9b3bb
Step 5/7 : COPY . .
 ---> 317348f86075
Step 6/7 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in e43752bea2dd
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (21.0.1)
Removing intermediate container e43752bea2dd
 ---> 1ce0ff9deb41
Step 7/7 : RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
 ---> Running in 87fb8a9db240
Collecting Django==2.2.17
  Downloading Django-2.2.17-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 MB)
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting sqlparse>=0.2.2
  Downloading sqlparse-0.4.1-py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Installing collected packages: sqlparse, pytz, Django
Successfully installed Django-2.2.17 pytz-2021.1 sqlparse-0.4.1
Removing intermediate container 87fb8a9db240
 ---> 8471de36ee4d
Successfully built 8471de36ee4d
Successfully tagged python:3.10.0a7-alpine3.13
[root@MySite Django]# 

[root@MySite Django]# docker image ls
REPOSITORY    TAG                   IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
python        3.10.0a7-alpine3.13   8471de36ee4d   8 minutes ago   86.5MB
python        <none>                bba91cdea5a1   3 days ago      44.9MB
django_2.2    iot                   37c35b93c3d8   6 days ago      86.3MB
```

Am I missing some steps from the Docker documentation?

Comment: If your `docker-compose.yml` file has both `image:` and `build:`, the `image:` is used as the name of the final image; you're telling Compose to overwrite the official Python image with your own.  You should delete the `image:` line (and `docker rmi python:3.10.0a7-alpine3.13`), and some of the behavior will hopefully be clearer.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. But I still did not understand how "telling compose to overwrite the official Python image with your own" is related to my problem? Beside, assuming you are right, this insight was not mentioned and clearly explained in below official document url, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build, which would waste time of many developers.

Comment: @DavidMaze, I delete my previously-built image, and run docker-compose again, it now build a new image with all RUN / COPY / CMD commands in dockerfile. All work perfectly. Perhaps, "image: " line asks docker daemon to check if this image exist locally. If yes, then directly use it without building a new one. When I delete that image manually, docker daemon can not find that image, hence build a new one. I guess this was what you meant in your above comment.  But, in Docker official guide, "image: " line is only for rename final image, never say impacting image building. that is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete my previously-built image, and run docker-compose again, it now build a new image and executing all RUN / COPY / CMD commands in dockerfile. All work perfectly.
Based on above behavior, it seems that "image: " line in docker-compose file asks docker daemon to check if this image exist locally. If yes, then directly use it without building a new one. When I delete that image manually, docker daemon can not find that image, hence build a new one.
According to Docker official guide, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#build,
"image: " line is only for rename final image, never say it would check if image already existed, and possibly impacting image building. The official guide is not precise and accurate in this regard.